# Accessing ghosted chunks with dask

Tags: dask

Using dask, I would like to break up an image array into overlapping tiles, perform a computation (on all the tiles simultaneously), and then stitch the results back into an image.

The following works, but feels clumsy:

```
from dask import array as da
from dask.array import ghost

import numpy as np


test_data = np.random.random((50, 50))
x = da.from_array(test_data, chunks=(10, 10))

depth = {0: 1, 1: 1}
g = ghost.ghost(x, depth=depth, boundary='reflect')

# Calculate the shape of the array in terms of chunks
chunk_shape = [len(c) for c in g.chunks]
chunk_nr = np.prod(chunk_shape)

# Allocate a list for results (as many entries as there are chunks)
blocks = [None,] * chunk_nr

def pack_block(block, block_id):
    """Store `block` at the correct position in `blocks`,
    according to its `block_id`.

    E.g., with ``block_id == (0, 3)``, the block will be stored at
    ``blocks[3]`.
    """
    idx = np.ravel_multi_index(block_id, chunk_shape)
    blocks[idx] = block

    # We don't really need to return anything, but this will do
    return block

g.map_blocks(pack_block).compute()

# Do some operation on the blocks; this is an over-simplified example.
# Typically, I want to do an operation that considers *all*
# blocks simultaneously, hence the need to first unpack into a list.
blocks = [b**2 for b in blocks]

def retrieve_block(_, block_id):
    """Fetch the correct block from the results set, `blocks`.
    """
    idx = np.ravel_multi_index(block_id, chunk_shape)
    return blocks[idx]

result = g.map_blocks(retrieve_block)

# Slice off excess from each computed chunk
result = ghost.trim_internal(result, depth)
result = result.compute()
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same end result?

Comment: Is it possible to add some context or an example of how the unpacked list is needed?  Perhaps goes without saying, but the current calc could be done like `ghost.trim_internal(g.map_blocks(lambda b: b**2), depth)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-facing api for this is [map_overlap](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.Array.map_overlap) method

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1])
>>> x = da.from_array(x, chunks=5)
>>> def derivative(x):
...     return x - np.roll(x, 1)

>>> y = x.map_overlap(derivative, depth=1, boundary=0)
>>> y.compute()
array([ 1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0])
```

Two additional notes for your use case

1. Avoid hashing costs by supplying name=False to from_array.  This saves you about 400MB/s assuming you don't have any fancy hashing libraries around.

   ```
   x = da.from_array(x, name=False)
   ```
2. Be careful of computing inplace.  Dask doesn't guarantee correct behavior if user functions mutate data inplace.  In this particular case it's probably fine, since we're copying for ghosting anyway, but it's something to be aware of.

#### Second answer

Given the comment by @stefan-van-der-walt we'll try another solution.

Consider using the [.to_delayed()](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.Array.to_delayed) method to get an array of chunks as [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) objects

```
depth = {0: 1, 1: 1}
g = ghost.ghost(x, depth=depth, boundary='reflect')
blocks = g.todelayed()
```

This gives you a numpy array of dask.delayed objects, each of which point to a block.  You can now perform arbitrary parallel computations on these blocks.  If I wanted them all to arrive at the same function then I might call the following:

```
result = dask.delayed(f)(blocks.tolist())
```

The function `f` will then get a list of lists of numpy arrays, each of which corresponds to one block in the dask.array `g`.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear when I mentioned "on all the tiles simultaneously".  I literally need a list of all the arrays, to operate on them, and to pack them back in.  But I can see how this would perhaps be abuse of dask for a job it wasn't really intended for.

Comment: See edit with second answer that uses [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html)